# YII Booster Select2Row don't work after renderpartial

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, renderpartial

I'm trying to use the yiibooster select2row widget in a view updated via ajax.
I have a select2row with the list of name of people retrieved by model.

After selecting one I try to update the other fields in the view by ajax and renderpartial.
I do that registeriing a script for the on change event.

It works the 1st time, but after the renderpartial it don't work anymore ... and even the widget is not rendered correctly anymore.

Here is my controller action

```
public function ActionView() {
    // Model Setting
    if(isset($_POST[idKey]) and $_POST[idKey] > 0) {
        $docente=Docente::model()->findByPk($_POST[idKey]);
    } else {
        $docente=new Docente();
    }

    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
        echo CJSON::encode(array(
                'divFormScheda'=>$this->renderPartial('_form',array('docente'=>$docente,), true, false),
            ));
        } else {
            $this->render('view', array('docente'=>$docente,));
        }
    }
```

Here my view

```
// Script to make the ajax update on change of the select2 widget
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('wric', "
jQuery('#Docente_id').on('change', function(e) {
    var idKey = $('#Docente_id').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        'url':'/regele/docente/view',
        'data':$(this).serialize() + '&idKey=' + idKey,
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'success':function(data) {
            $('#divFormScheda').html(data.divFormScheda);
        },
        'cache':false
    });
    return false;
});
");



    //
    // Display Scheda
    //
    echo CHtml::openTag('div',array('id'=>'divFormScheda'));
    $this->renderPartial('_form', array('docente'=>$docente,), false, false);    
    echo CHtml::closeTag('div');
```

And here my _form.php used in renderpartial

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'idFormR',
        'type' => 'horizontal',
        'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'well'),
    )
);

// Error
echo $form->errorSummary($docente,"Errori riscontrati:<br /><br />");

// Input Hidden to read the idKey to set the ajax post
echo $form->hiddenField($docente, 'id', array('id' => 'idKey'));

// select2row widget for the selection
echo $form->select2Row($docente, 'id',
    array(
        'data' => CHtml::listData(Docente::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'cognome'),
        'options' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Select ...',
            'allowClear' => true,
            'width' => '40%',
        )
    )
);

// Fields
echo $form->textFieldRow($docente, 'nome', array('class' => 'input-xlarge', 'disabled' => true));

$this->endWidget();
```

In the form I used an hidden field to store the id used in the script to send the ajax request via POST.

Really I don't understand why it works only the first time .....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set processOutput to true i.e :

```
$this->renderPartial('_form',array('docente'=>$docente,), true, true);
```

It should work this way

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I'm still seeing the same problem as the OP.